# Add image on SurfaceView in Android

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I have to implement a function in my Android app that allow me to insert a "marker" on a SurfaceView.

What that I need is simple:
when I touch on the screen, a function capture the coordinates (x,y) of my touch, in this moment I need to show a marker in this position.

The marker can be removed later doing a tap on the marker (and eventually eliminate it through a menu)

What is the best way to do this ?

Is it possible create programmatically a imageView on the surfaceView or is better draw a bitmap with canvas?

Comment: I suggest you to use Canvas instead of surface view

Comment: @kapil.dev so is it better use Canvas and draw a Bitmap ?

Comment: yeah that approach is good

Comment: With this approach can I specify the coordinates where the Bitmap must appear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use a TileView, look this link [TileView](https://github.com/moagrius/TileView)

Does exactly what you are asking